# Start multiple NSTask with root privilege asking for password only once

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, root, privileges, nstask

I would like to start a lot of `NSTask`s that require root privilege, I found that I should use Apple's Authorization Kit and I found [`STPrivilegedTask`](https://github.com/sveinbjornt/STPrivilegedTask), which is designed for that.

The thing is, when I start a `STPrivilegedTask`, it will ask me for the root password each time. Is there a way to enter the root password for the first privileged task, and then for the other tasks, the application will remember the root password, so the user won't have to enter the password again and again and again?

Comment: Are you going to submit this application to Mac App Store?

Comment: No I wont, it's an app for my personal use only ;)

Comment: Did you find a way ?